# Spawn of a local player and a non-local player with different prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have a problem with the spawn of a local player and other players, I need the prefab of a local player to be different when spawning from the prefabs of other players.

Simply put:

- so that a *player* has a prefab **A** on his device and *other players* have prefabs **B**
- I want to make sure that the player on his device **does not** execute unnecessary scripts of *other players*

How can this be implemented?

I know that you can spawn everyone the same, and then delete, add and change the necessary components, but I don't want to do that.

I use Mirror for multiplayer

Comment: in your network code, just send a model type for said other player

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the same prefab for a local and remote players, consider using *[Prefab Variants](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PrefabVariants.html)*.

Unity has this to say (my emphasis):

> Prefab Variants are useful when you want to have a set of predefined variations of a Prefab

> For example, you might want to have several different types of GermSlimeTargets in your game, which are all based on the same basic GermSlimeTarget Prefab. However you may want some GermSlimeTargets to carry items, some to move at **different speeds**, or some to emit **extra sound effects**.

e.g.

```
SoldierPrefab
|  * script1
|  * script2
|
|-- LocalPlayerPrefab (includes everything in SoldierPrefab)
|  * hudScript
|  * inventoryScript
|  * sendUpdatesScript
|  * processInputScript
|
|-- RemotePlayerPrefab (includes everything in SoldierPrefab)
|  * killPlayerScript
   * receiveUpdatesScript
```